# Trying to populate a list of JSON objects in a get request?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

I have a get request which contains a list of JSON objects which i want to populate on the screen in a input field with data binding like ng-model the JSON get request is as follows :

```
[{"make":"Mahindra","vin":"1987","model":"XUV","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Nissan","vin":"2039","model":"Terrano","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Toyota","vin":"2456","model":"Camry","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Skoda","vin":"5012","model":"Rapid","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Toyota","vin":"1234","model":"FJ","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Ford","vin":"3401","model":"Ikon","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Tata","vin":"4568","model":"Nano","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]}]
```

I had writen a ng-repeat for the lists but it rendered a blank input field,
the script looks like this along with the html code :

```
  <form>
    <table id="tableRow" class="table table-bordered tableRow">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th><label>Make</label></th>
          <th><label>Vin</label></th>
          <th><label>Model</label></th>
          <th><label>Parts</label></th>
          <th><label></label></th>
          <th><label></label></th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="i in myRow">
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gs"></i></button></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid"  ng-model="myRow[i].make"></td> 
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vinid" ng-model="myRow[i].vin"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalid" ng-model="myRow[i].model"></td>
          <td ng-repeat="part in myRow.item.parts"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.name"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.desc"></td> 
        </tr>
      </thead>    
    <tbody id="tableROW">
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myRowSub()">Submit</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="myGet()">get</button>
  </form>
```

How do i parse the JSON object like we do in single object LIKE myRow.parts ???

the GET Code is as follows:

```
<script>
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("http://172.17.133.82:8080/restproj/v1/dealer/1234/allcar")
                    .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.myRow = response.data;    
                });
                   $http.get("http://192.168.11.82:8080/restproj/v1/dealer")
                    .then(function(response) {
                    $scope.myRow = response.data;

                });
</script>
```

The get request holds the JSON data in scope myRow. So how can i access the individual parts to render it on the screen.
How can i also only post individual records instead of posting the entire form Data.....

Answer (score 0):

Instead of it `ng-model="myRow[i].make`" should be  `ng-model="i.make"`

```
<tr ng-repeat="i in myRow">
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gs"></i></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid" ng-model="i.make">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vinid" ng-model="i.vin">
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalid" ng-model="i.model">
            </td>
            <td ng-repeat="part in i.parts">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.name">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.desc">
            </td>
          </tr>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IXhrPLKbd50IJbussHAO?p=preview)**

Comment: but there are 3 mode data in part of which only one data of name and desc is being populated....!! i needed all the the data of parts to be shown on the screen

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr ng-repeat="rowItem in myRow">
    <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gs"></i></button></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid" ng-model="rowItem.make"></td> 
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vinid" ng-model="rowItem.vin"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalid" ng-model="rowItem.model"></td>
    <td ng-repeat="part in rowItem.item.parts"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.name"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.desc"></td> 
</tr>
```

Does this work for you?
You was using myRow[i], but the i is the row item, so I changed it to rowItem in the repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {

  $scope.jsonObj = [{"make":"Mahindra","vin":"1987","model":"XUV","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Nissan","vin":"2039","model":"Terrano","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Toyota","vin":"2456","model":"Camry","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Skoda","vin":"5012","model":"Rapid","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Toyota","vin":"1234","model":"FJ","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Ford","vin":"3401","model":"Ikon","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]},{"make":"Tata","vin":"4568","model":"Nano","parts":[{"name":"wheel","desc":"makes it roll"},{"name":"engine","desc":"really shiny"},{"name":"Seats","desc":"leather seat covers"}]}];
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form>
    <table id="tableRow" class="table table-bordered tableRow">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th><label>Make</label></th>
          <th><label>Vin</label></th>
          <th><label>Model</label></th>
          <th><label>Parts</label></th>
          <th><label></label></th>
          <th><label></label></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>    
    <tbody id="tableROW">
            <tr ng-repeat="i in jsonObj">
          <td><button class="btn btn-danger btn-remove" type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash gs"></i></button></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="makeid"  ng-model="i.make"></td> 
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="vinid" ng-model="i.vin"></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalid" ng-model="i.model"></td>
          <td ng-repeat="part in i.parts"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.name"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="partsid" ng-model="part.desc"></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </form>
</div>
```